# How to remove “start a work flow” from my publish tab

Tags: development, page-layout, custom-field-types

I have created a new List Workflow inside SharePoint designer , and I publish the workflow. But currently I got the following new entry under the Publish tab :-

[image]

Although i specify that users cannot manually start workflow  !!! , so is there a way to hide this ?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you have a publishing site setup with approval workflow. You can delete the workflow if it is not needed. The library that the pages are on may also have content approval turned on and again if not needed, you could turn that off.

Comment: i need the workflow, but I specified that users can not start the workflow manually,and the workflow will start automatically when an item is created or changed. so having this option inside the "Publish" tab is wrong, as users can not start workflow manually as i have specified inside the workflow settings !!

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Your SPD workflow is not what that workflow button is for. That is for starting the Publishing approval workflow which is not the one you created in SPD. That button tells me that you have a publishing approval workflow on the Pages library or the library the page is in.

Comment: no i do not think so, because if i remove the workflow which i have created, the icons will be removed from the Publish tab..

Comment: I have done this many times. I have seen many publishing sites and publishing approval workflows show this, but I have never seen a page publishing tab have this without that workflow. The image you display shows editing a page. Is the workflow on the page library?

Comment: the "Publish" tab itself is shown because i specify that content on this library requires approval. but after creating the workflow, the "workflow" section was added to the "Publish" tab, although i have specified not to allow users to start the workflow manually...

Comment: What list/library is the SPD workflow attached to? The content on this library requires approval is the approval workflow I was talking about.

Comment: no i ment that the "Publish" tab was shown when i set the Versioning setting inside the page library to "Require content approval". and the "workflow" section inside the "Publish" tab was displayed after creating my custom workflow/